# How to get vmware to run a program within MAC OS X via script or alias

Tags: visual-studio, macos, scripting, vmware

On my Mac OS X computer, I am trying to setup a script that will open a particular program ( Visual Studio ) that resides within VMWare.

More specifically, when I run the script, I want Visual Studio application to open a specific file that would passed in as a parameter to the script. This file would be shared and accessible to VS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Complex solution - There are scripting interfaces to VMware (at least the server versions)

Simple solution - have the visual studio in your Windows (in the VM) startup folder, and have it set to open the last solution. If you need to change the solution you can have it point to a link on the Mac filesystem and change where the link points before starting VM.

You might also want to ask on serverfault